# Is it possible to run a find_by_sql query in Rails / ActiveRecord without loading all results into memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm building a Rails plugin that extracts a lot of data from Rails apps. It builds queries dynamically that span multiple tables, and there will be a lot of results returned. Here's an example of one of the queries built for pulling purchase data out of a Spree (Rails shopping cart):

`select orders.user_id as from_id, variants.product_id as to_id from orders, line_items, variants where orders.user_id is not null and variants.product_id is not null and orders.id = line_items.order_id and line_items.variant_id = variants.id order by from_id;`

The problem is that ActiveRecord loads up all results into memory. Is there a way to avoid that without dropping down to writing DB-specific code?  (I'm aware of find_each, but that doesn't allow for sorting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jaime's answer led me along a more productive path of queries landing at [will_paginate](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki), which offers a paginate_by_sql method.  With a teency bit of effort, that was wrapped up in a paginated SQL each:

```
def paginated_sql_each(query, &block)
  page = 1
  begin
    results = paginate_by_sql(query, :page => page)
    results.each { |r| block.call(r) }
    page += 1
  end while !results.empty?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible, and here's an article that walks through it:

http://www.rubyinside.com/paginate_by_sql-rails-pagination-on-your-own-sql-queries-50.html

They have code you can copy verbatim, but the key is using SQL's `count` method.  With this code, you can call `paginate_by_sql` instead of `find_by_sql`, and you pass in the page and per-page params.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also want to look into, Rails ActiveRecord batches, to retrieve records in smaller chunks:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches

Comment: find_in_batches is just like find_each in that it doesn't support ordering (or custom SQL).